# Wrong keyboard layout on client PC when using synergy

Tags: 11.10, 10.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, synergy

I just installed ubuntu 11.10 in my new computer, the old one (still main computer) is ubuntu 10.04. Both PCs use "Spanish LAm" keyboard layout, the only difference is that the new PC keyboard has some multimedia keys but the configs are the same and the work well each one on each PC.

But when I use synergy to use the main keyboard in the client PC (11.10), the keyboard layout seems to be the "Enlglish (US)" layout, or other but not "Spanish LAm", while settings on both PCs remain as "Spanish LAm". The other keyboard connected by cable to the client PC does work well with the spanish layout even when using synergy.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I removed 11.10 and installed 11.04, I don't have the problem with this version.

Comment: "The issue is actually not fixed, but was instead closed because it's too broad." https://github.com/symless/synergy-core/issues/6005#issuecomment-426570946

Answer (score 12):

In my case synergy seams simply to ignore actual keyboard layout but it helps if I set it after starting synergyc.

```
synergyc myhost
setxkbmap us -option grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

You will find correct values for `setxkbmap` arguments in file `/etc/default/keyboard`. Instead of `us` place value of `XKBLAYOUT` and pass value of `XKBOPTIONS` to `-options`.

You can use this simple script to do this automatically:

```
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/default/keyboard
synergyc $1
setxkbmap $XKBLAYOUT -option "$XKBOPTIONS" -model "$XKBMODEL" \
                     -variant "$XKBVARIANT"
```

Save it as `mysynergyc`, set correct permissions (`chmod 755 mysynergyc`) and then run as usual instead of `synergyc`.

Answer (score 4):

1. Search for "Keyboard Layout" and open it.
2. Use the plus sign on the
   bottom left of the screen to add the keyboard layout "English(US)".
3. Restart synergy

This worked for me. (Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit)

Comment: I have the same problem in 12.04, though with Norwegian keymap and Windows 7 on the server side. It used to work flawlessly for me in 11.10 with the same setup. The suggestion in this answer does not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with my Windows server / Ubuntu client configuration.
At work I had the setup the other way around and it worked like a dream.

As a workaround a added an another keymap to the Ubuntu client. Then while using Synergy switched the keymap from en to de and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

Stop the synergy server, reset keyboard layout in server, then restart synergy seems to solve the problem in my situtation. Original reference is here: 
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=580504#15

Answer (score 0):

In my case, running Ubuntu 22-04, I open the synergy window (on the machine I had the problem), went on Keyboard & Mouse, and turned off "Alt G for PC keyboards only" in the advanced section. That solved the problem.